# github merge up to a specific commit

Tags: git, github, merge, git-commit

Git allows one to merge up to a specific commit. For example, merging the master branch up to a commit on dev which is not necessarily the latest commit. The command for this is as follows:

```
git merge <commitId>
```

The github web application allows one to manage their branches by kicking of a merge. One accomplishes this using "Create a pull request" under the "Compare Changes" view. I'm confused by the interface because, if I specify a changeset rather than a branch for comparison, github will not give me the option of starting a pull request (though it will perform the comparison).

Does anyone know whether it is possible to accomplish a merge up to a specific changeset or tag from the github webapp?

Answer (score 2):

Github pull request are made for branches.

If you like to merge upto specific change, go to that commit using

```
git checkout <commit-id>
```

create a git branch from there

```
 git branch <branch-name>
```

create a pull request from the newly created branch.

Example: check this [link](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/pull/289), it says *rajuGT  wants to merge 1 commit into sstephenson:**master** from rajuGT:**Object_isObject**.* 
here master is sstephenson repository's main branch and Object_isObject is a topic branch which is asked for pull request.

Note: Any changes made after pull request to the pull request branch, will be considered in the pull request. So always try to use topic branches for patches.

Comment: My problem is that I already have a branch, but that our testing has passed on a changeset earlier than the latest one. So, the main trunk has changeset (A.B.C) and the branch has changesets (D,E). I want to merge changeset D into the trunk but NOT changeset E. The command in my OP will do this, but I was hoping it to be possible from directly inside the github webapp.

Comment: As far I know, there is no such feature from github. But you can always have option to do this in command line, by checking out D commit n create branch, then merge it.